# Where can I get the GGLContext+Analytics category required for google analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-analytics

I am implementing the google analytics in one of my iOS application, I found that they added some configuration plist that required to add to the project to track proper analytics.

I created the required configuration file and started adding the analytics by following the steps mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#add-config

Now, moving towards adding some code:

```
//Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
NSError *configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
```

I am not be able to find this class GGLContext, I found the documentation for this class here:

https://developers.google.com/ios/reference/interface_g_g_l_context

but not getting the framework. I tried with the pods, but due to proxy issues, I was not be able to run the pods.

Any idea?

Thanks